# How to save the value of table cell using JavaScript and AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to save the flight number to be able to access it in another html page using the controller and service

**My code**

```
<table class="headers">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Choose Flight</th>                    
            <th> Departs From</th>
            <th> Destination</th>
            <th> Departs </th>
            <th> Flight Number </th>                   
            <th > Price </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    </div>
    </td>

    <tbody ng-repeat="flight in flights" >
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="id">
        </td>

        <!--  <tr ng-repeat="Flight in Flights"> -->
        <!--     <td>{{Flight.FlightNumber}}</td> -->

        <td>{{flight.origin}}</td>
        <td>{{flight.destination}}</td>
        <td>{{flight.departureDate}}</td>
        <td>{{flight.flightNumber}}</td>
        <td>{{p}}</td>
        <!--   </tr> -->
    </tbody>     
</table>
```

Comment: @javascript  #javascript

Comment: Can you add your JS code please ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you using Angular 1 (is it true to Angular 2 anyway).

You have to bind value to your controller by using `ng-model` (using input). Then store it at your convenience (session, database...) and pass it to an other page.

There is documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: I could not add any input as i'm retrieving the flight number from the database .. if you have any solution i would be grateful

Comment: My Javascript doesn't contain anything related to the flightnumber, i don't what should i add to be able to save it.